# Is there a way to create a dataframe for each unique value in a pandas column and then write each one to a different sheet in the same Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working with a dataset that contains a count of the number of vehicles passing by a sensor each hour over the course of several days. A subset of the data is below:

| SET NAME | DIRECTION | DATE INTERVAL | START TIME | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 20/08/2021 | 19:00 | 498 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 20/08/2021 | 20:00 | 372 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 20/08/2021 | 21:00 | 202 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 20/08/2021 | 22:00 | 129 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 20/08/2021 | 23:00 | 89 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 21/08/2021 | 00:00 | 20 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 21/08/2021 | 01:00 | 32 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 21/08/2021 | 02:00 | 23 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 21/08/2021 | 03:00 | 25 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 26/08/2021 | 16:00 | 857 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 26/08/2021 | 17:00 | 813 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 26/08/2021 | 18:00 | 585 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 26/08/2021 | 19:00 | 524 |
| Site 4019-SCO_S261_C1 | N1 | 26/08/2021 | 20:00 | 959 |

I want to select each unique date interval and save it to its own dataframe, and once I've done that I'd like to write each date to its own sheet in an excel .xlsx workbook (the name of which doesn't matter).

I have tried to use the code below which does work but only seems to save a sheet with the last date interval (in this sample case 26/08/2021)

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("combined_count.xlsx") as writer:
    for date, data in combined_count.groupby('DATE'):
        data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = date)
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your code works for me (Python 3.8.2, pandas 1.1.0), but only if I replace the forward slashes in the date with `sheet_name = date.replace('/', '_')`. Not sure whether this makes sense to you because we don't know if your date column is of the `str` or `datetime` data type.

Comment: Yeah that literally solved it for me to, must've just been something to do with the slashes

Answer (score 0):

As jfaccioni said in their comment it was simply due to the slashes in the date column

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("combined_count.xlsx") as writer:
    for date, data in combined_count.groupby('DATE'):
        data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = date.replace('/', '_'))
```

The above code now works as intended